# Command to recursively delete all files with changing extension number

Tags: recursive, delete

I know how to delete recursively all files with a specific extension, but how about if that extension has a number appended to it?

For example, how can I delete files named `.d3plot1`, `.d3plot2`, `.d3plot4`, etc.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ find /path/ -type f -name "*.d3plot*" -print -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Answer (score -1):

please try:

```
sudo rm -f ./*.d3plot*
```

Comment: Wow, that worked. Thank you!!

Comment: `sudo` seems like it could be overkill here

Comment: What makes this recursive?